# Prove that $\beta⟘U$ for some $\beta \in W/\{0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, there are given $m$-dimensional subspaces $U$ and $W$ so that $\alpha⟘W$  ($\alpha$ is orthogonal to every vector in $W$) for some $\alpha \in U/\{0\}$ . Prove that $\beta⟘U$  for some $\beta \in W/\{0\}$.

Okay, I know that if $\alpha⟘W$, then $(\alpha|w)=0, w \in W$. I'm pretty lost after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\dim (U \cap W^{\perp}) \geq 1$ and you want to show that $\dim (W \cap U^{\perp}) \geq 1$. Note that

$$ \dim (W \cap U^{\perp}) = \dim W + \dim U^{\perp} - \dim (W + U^{\perp}) = m + (n - m) - \dim (W + U^{\perp}) \\ = n - \dim (W + U^{\perp}) $$

so it is enough to show that $\dim \left(W + U^{\perp}\right) \leq n - 1$ or, equivalently, that $\dim \left(W + U^{\perp}\right)^{\perp} \geq 1$.

Indeed, we have
$$ (W + U^{\perp})^{\perp} = W^{\perp} \cap \left( U^{\perp} \right)^{\perp} = W^{\perp} \cap U $$

which shows that $\dim W^{\perp} \cap U = \dim \left( W + U^{\perp} \right)^{\perp} \geq 1$.